# Product of Prime Factors of Group Order $\leq n \cdot (\frac n 2)^{\log{\frac n 2}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inequality, finite-groups

The product $\pi(G)$ is the product of all different primes dividing $|G|$. Let $G$ be a primitive group of degree $n$. $G$ has odd order. $G_x$ denotes the pointstabiliser of a point $x \in \Omega$. We call the orbits of a
pointstabiliser in a transitive group suborbits.

**Definition of** $G^{\Delta}$: $Sym(\Omega)$ -the symmetric group on the set $\Omega$. , If $G < Sym(\Omega)$, and $\Delta$ is a subset of $\Omega$ fixed by $G$, then the image of the action of $G$ on $\Delta$ is called the permutation group induced on $\Delta$  by $G$, and written $G^{\Delta}$.

In an [article (link given)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08266.pdf) following lemmas are given :

> **Lemma 1.** *Let $G$ be a primitive group of degree $n$ and $G_x$ a pointstabiliser. If a prime $p$ divides $|G_x|$ then $p$ divides $|G_x^{\Delta}|$ for all suborbits $\Delta$ of length at least $2$.*
>
> Recall that the *exponent* of a group is the smallest common multiple of the orders of its elements.
>
> **Lemma 2.** *Let $G$ be a transitive group of degree $n$. If $G$ has odd order then the exponent of $G$ is at most $n^{(\log n)^2}$.*
>
> *Proof.* We will actually prove the following claim:
>
> **Claim.** *The product $\pi(G)$ of all different primes dividing $|G|$ is at most $n^{\log n}$.*
>
> Since any element of $G$ of prime power order has order at most $n$, the claim implies our statement.
>
> Assume first that $G$ is primitive. Since $G$ has odd order, $G$ cannot be doulby transitive. The smallest non-trivial suborbit $\Delta$ has size $\lt \frac{n}{2}$. Lemma 1 implies that $\pi(G_x)=\pi(G_x^{\Delta})$. It is clear that $\pi(G)$ divides $n\cdot \pi(G_x)$, hence by induction $\pi(G)\leq n\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\log\frac{n}{2}}\leq n^{\log n}$.
>
> Assume now that $G$ is imprimitive. Let $B_1$ be a minimal non-trivial block of imprimitivity (of size $b$) and $B_1,\ldots,B_k$ the corresponding system of blocks of imprimitivity. Then $G$ permutes these blocks transitively, let $K$ denote the kernel of this action. By induction $\pi(G/K)\leq k^{\log k}$.
>
> We may assume that $K\neq 1$. Then the minimality of $B_1$ implies that $K$ acts transitively on each $B_i$, adn the corresponding transitive groups are permutation equivalent. Hence $\pi(K)=\pi(K^{B_1})\leq b^{\log b}$.
>
> Using $kb=n$ we obtain that $\pi(G)\leq n^{\log n}$. This complets the proof. $\Box$

I am trying to understand following 2 lines of lemma 2 :

> It is clear that $\pi(G)$ divides $n · \pi(G_x)$,

and

> hence by induction $\pi(G) \leq  n \cdot (\frac n 2)^{\log{\frac n 2}} \leq n^{\log n}$.

**How those the last line $\pi(G) \leq  n \cdot (\frac n 2)^{\log{\frac n 2}} \leq n^{\log n}$ was obtained by induction?**

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: To expand: pictures are not searchable, they are not accessible, and they do not adapt to different displays. that makes your post difficult to find through searches, and impossible to read to many.

Comment: The first part is easy: $|G|=n|G_x|$, so $\pi(G)\mid n\pi(G_x)$. For the second part, he states that $\pi(G_x)=\pi(G_x^\Delta)$ and that $G_x^\Delta$ is the orbit of length less than $n/2$. Then plug in.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven could u plz give me a hint from where we get $|G|=n|G_x|$ ?

Comment: From your second-year undergraduate group theory course? Orbit-Stabilizer theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am sorry for the picture but it is really not feasible to type such a large portion of text, btw I have included the link of original document, also, how do you search? as far I understand, math symbols don't get searched well in search engine and the symbol free text does not yield much! looking for your advice in this regard.

Comment: It is absolutely feasible to type up that portion. I will type it up for you (last time) and time it, just so you find out. If a  portion of text is truly too large to be typed, and the question is not understandable without such a large amount of text, then it is almost certainly not suitable for this site. The search engine on the site is not terribly good, but there are [alternatives such as Approach Zero](approach0.xyz/search).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin don't type it, I will start doing it within 20 minuets.

Comment: This section doesn't even contain the definition of $G_x^\Delta$, without which your second question cannot be answered anyway.

Comment: @MRJames2017: Too late. And it took me a little over 6 minutes, even though I needed to fire up my iPad because I couldn't see what I was typing and the picture at the same time. Hardly "not feasible".

Comment: @MRJames2017 You solved the first part with orbit-stabilizer theorem. The second is just inserting the one formula inside another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is transitive, $|G|=n\cdot |G_x|$ by the orbit-stabilizer theorem. If $p\mid |G|$ then either $p\mid n$ or $p\mid |G_x|$. Thus $$\pi(G)\leq \pi(n)\cdot \pi(G_x)\leq n\cdot \pi(G_x).$$

That's the first point. For the second, we already have $\pi(G)\leq n\cdot \pi(G_x)$. We also have that $\pi(G_x)\leq (n/2)^{\log(n/2)}$. We are trying to show by induction the following statement:

> For any group $G$ of odd order and degree $n$, $\pi(G)\leq n^{\log n}$.

Thus we can substitute in:
$$ \pi(G)\leq n\cdot \pi(G_x)\leq n\cdot (n/2)^{\log(n/2)}.$$
So the question is whether the final term is at most $n^{\log n}$. This isn't really a question about group theory, but it's not hard to see.

Comment: You do not have $\pi(G_x)\leq n/2$, that is definitely not true. $n/2$ is the size of the set that $G_x^\Delta$ can act on. So by induction, $\pi(G_x)=\pi(G_x^\Delta)\leq (n/2)^{\log(n/2))$.

Comment: @MRJames2017 It was a typo, now corrected. The 'assume true for $n$, prove true for $n+1$' is the basic form of induction taught at school. Induction is 'if you have any collection of objects with an invariant with values in $\mathbb N$ (e.g., size, dimension), and the result holds for all objects with smaller invariant, prove your result holds for a given value of the invariant'.

Comment: @MRJames2017 I understand that you are at a loss. However, the general principle of structural induction, of a more general induction than purely $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$, is a 1st-year undergraduate mathematics topic. You were asking for help on a research-level paper in finite group theory. If you don't understand basic notions of mathematics, what exactly do you expect to get out of this paper?