# Consequence of having group degree less than $\frac n 2$ of group $G_x^{\Delta}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a primitive group of degree $n$, $G$ have odd order, and $G_x$ denote the pointstabiliser of a point $x \in \Omega$.

We call the orbits of a pointstabiliser in a transitive group suborbits.

**Definition of** $G^{\Delta}$: ${\rm Sym}(\Omega)$ -the symmetric group on the set $\Omega$. , If $G < {\rm Sym}(\Omega)$, and $\Delta$ is a subset of $\Omega$ fixed by $G$, then the image of the action of $G$ on $\Delta$ is called the permutation group induced on $\Delta$  by $G$, and written $G^{\Delta}$ ([see this doc](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08266.pdf)).

Then, $G_x^{\Delta}$ denotes the permutation group induced by the action of $G_x$ on $\Delta$ ([see page 2, 3](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/%7Epotocnik/research/Stabiliser.pdf)).

Since $G$ has odd order, $G$ cannot be doulby transitive. The smallest non-trivial suborbit $\Delta$ has size $\lt \frac{n}{2}$.

At this stage, can we say $G_x^{\Delta}$ has group degree less than $\frac n 2$ as $G_x^{\Delta}$ and $G_x$ are same group but acting on different set $\Delta, \Delta\cup \{x\}$ respectively?

If this is true then it can be used [in this induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4234429/850314) (the inductive hypothesis is $\pi(group)\leq (\text{group degree})^{\log(\text{group degree})}$).

Comment: OK, apparently someone didn't like my previous comment and deleted it. So here are two reasons why your question is wrong. 1) No, we cannot say that the order of $G_x^\Delta$ is less than $n/2$, and we never did. 2) The inductive hypothesis is not what you claim, but it's (degree) to the power log(degree). This question is entirely based on a misunderstanding of a previous answer and therefore should be closed.

Comment: You are trying to read a research paper on permutation groups without knowing anything about permutation groups. Start with understanding the basics of permutation groups, before moving on to research topics. You've been struggling with page 2 of this paper for over a month now. This tells you that you aren't at the level needed to work on it yet.

Comment: OK, now you are asking a good question. Now you need Lemma 1. Although $G_x$ and $G_x^\Delta$ are (possibly) different groups, acting on different sets ($\Omega\setminus\{x\}$ and $\Delta$), the same primes divide their orders and so $\pi(G_x)=\pi(G_x^\Delta)$, which is what you wanted.